# How to fetch value from mysql to dropdown list?

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

i am newbie to PHP and MySql. I'm working on small project, some part of this project i have to deal with form and get value back to the field when i need to edit the text. Here's is what i meant

```
//dropdown list in Create 
<select name="color">
   while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
                    {
                      echo '<option>'.$row['colors'].'</option>';
                    }
 </select>
<input type="submit" name="submitcolor"/>

//dropdown list in Edit
<select name="color" value="???????">

</select>
```

i have no problem submit the value to MySql. The problem is, how to fetch the value back to dropdown list, so i don't have to click and search the value.

Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I didn't get it, please be more clear. Explain your algorithm's flow (**what** you get from **where** and to **where** it should go to happen **what**)

Comment: If you want to fill the second dropdown according to the values of the first one, you have some options like **1)** Point your form action to the same page and deal with the code (dirty) **2)** Use AJAX (clean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<//dropdown list in Create 
<select name="color">
<?php
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
   {
     echo '<option     value="'.$row['colors'].'">'.$row['colors'].'</option>';
   }
 ?>
</select>

  <input type="submit" name="submitcolor"/>

 //dropdown list in Edit
  <select name="color">

<?php
$color = 'some value you fetched from database';
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
   {
     $selected = '';
     if($color == $row['colors']) {
       $selected = 'selected';
     }
     echo '<option value="'.$row['colors'].'" '.$selected.'>'.$row['colors'].'</option>';
   }
 ?>
  </select>
```

You need to have a value in 'option' tag. And on editing, compare the exisiting 'color' value with the edit selectbox  value

Comment: Thank u @Arun Krish . I've tried ur code but it said error unindentified index : color $_post['color'].  any idea?

Comment: $_post['color'] is the value thats fetch after submitting the form containing select name='color'. Do you have create and edit in same page or different pages?

Comment: So, when you submit the form from create page, you are storing the color value in db. And in edit page, you do a SELECT query to fetch that color value and compare with the option value in Edit page.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can fill a drop down with mysql results

```
   <select name="name">                     
        <?php
            $count = count($name);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){    
                    "<option $type[$i]['name'] </option>';
                }
        ?>
    </select>
```